# Angular 2 using BehaviorSubject in custom RadioButton

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I need to build custom RadioButtons.  When one is selected, it calls a service who will send its identifier to all subscribed RadioButtons including the caller.  If the subscribe sees that the key (instance + id) is NOT the same as itself, it will uncheck itself otherwise the matching instance + id (who is indeed the caller) will remain as checked.
The service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class RadioButtonService {
  public Status_Subject: Subject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('x;y');
  constructor() {
  }
  public setRadioChecked(instance: string, id: string ) {
    const key = instance + ';' + id;
    this.Status_Subject.next(key);
  }
}
```

Relevant part of the component:

```
export class RadioButtonComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() instanceId: string;
  @Input() group: string;
  isdisabled = false;
  ischecked = false;
  subj: Subject<string>;
  constructor(private radSvc: RadioButtonService) {
    this.subj = this.radSvc.Status_Subject;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.subj.subscribe(
      (key) => {
        const parts = key.split(';');
        this.ischecked =  (key[0] !== this.instanceId || key[1] !== this.id ? false : true );
      }
    );
  }

  ClickEvent($event) {
    if (!this.isdisabled) {
      this.ischecked = !this.ischecked;
      this.radSvc.setRadioChecked(this.instanceId, this.id); // tell the world we got clicked
      // send to Store(instanceId, id, value);
    }
  }
```

The AfterViewInit() initializes the component's subject (I think) and is supposed to wait for the service to call.
When I click on a radiobutton, ClickEvent IS called in the component, I stepped to the setRadioChecked function in the service, the next(key) seems to execute, but it is never caught by the component's AfterViewInit subscribe.

What am I missing?

Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: I created a plunkr with your code and I'm able to get everything working fine: https://plnkr.co/edit/WzZvZNU6S8uPOb85gqZO

Comment: Ah!!! yes it does... comparing the fine details of the plunker with my own code, I see I messed up one line that feeds in the id.  THANKS SO MUCH for your help.  I wish I could check this as the answer!  Yogi.

Comment: No problem. Glad to know it helped. Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a plunkr with your code and I'm able to get everything working fine: plnkr.co/edit/WzZvZNU6S8uPOb85gqZO